# Blazor Wasm starting and exiting without hitting user code in program.cs

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I have a problem where my Blazor Wasm (.net 6.0) project won't run in debug mode. It compiles, opens a browser and points to localhost with the correct port but then fails with no error message. The browser window disappears as if the program exited normally.

It was working absolutely fine last night and just seems to have stopped overnight. Any ideas on how to debug?

Answer (score 1):

No joy in trying to debug this - a new blazor wasm project runs fine, but as soon as I start adding scripts to load bootstrap it fails again.

What worked for me was to exit VS, delete the .vs folder in the project root and then open VS again.

Comment: Hi #Liam, today it happened to me the same thing. Your solution worked great! I don't know what was going wrong. Anyway thanks to share your solution.

Comment: It happened to me again this morning whilst I was working - it affects both this version of VS (Community 17.5.2) and the previous one

Answer (score 0):

Ok, while deleting the .vs folder does work it has become extremely tedious when this issue keeps on occurring every 5 minutes.

The problem seems to related to breakpoints that exist in the code when you run the app. I have found that if you delete all breakpoints from your code (CTRL-SHIFT-F9) the app runs without crashing.

The issue has been reported here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/47238

Answer (score 0):

Blazor debugging seems to be broken by a chromium update. [Reddit post with link to Microsoft](https://www.reddit.com/r/Blazor/comments/11s311p/windows_security_update_from_315_breaks_blazor/)

One person replied it could be fixed by downgrading Edge.

Also adding breakpoints while debugging seems to trigger this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgraded to Edge 111.0.1661.43 and can now run with breakpoints already set in my project.